# Multiple Instance 2008 R2 SSRS. Upgraded one to 2014. Now getting Invalid Class error with 2008 Report Config Manager

Tags: reporting-services

We have a Windows Server 2008 box that has multiple instances of SQL 2008R2 SSRS installed along with SQL Server.  Upgraded one instance of SQL Server and SSRS to SQL 2014.  Now when I open 2008 Reporting Services Configuration Manager no instances show up.  If I click the Find button I get 'Invalid Class' error. If I open the 2014 Reporting Services Configuration Manager I see just the instance that was upgraded.  Any ideas?